# If $H\subseteq G$ is a cocompact subgroup, then $G=KH$ for $K\subseteq G$ compact subgroup

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, compactness, quotient-group

The question is in the title. $H\subseteq G$ is called cocompact if $G/H$ is a compact space.

This is a well-known fact but I couldn't prove it myself.

I would be happy as well for a reference, which I failed finding myself.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Mistake in the title, I meant $K$ compact subset in $G$. As already answered here, it is not possible if one requires $K$ sub-group.

Comment: Reference: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocompact_group_action), or [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110407/characterization-of-cocompact-group-action).

Answer (score 2):

There is no reference and this isn't wellknown, because it's easily seen to be false. Simple example: $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $0<H<G$. $G/H$ is finite and therefore compact, but the only compact subgroup of $G$ is $0$ itself so that $K+H\neq G$. Similarly one could choose $G=\mathbb{R}$ and $0<H<G$ or $G=\mathbb{R}^n$ and any lattice of maximal dimension. And there are many, many more examples.

Comment: Oh no, thank you. I meant compact subset, and not subgroup! So sorry, I will Correct now the question.